# Recyclerview v7:27.1.1 wrap_content Not Working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I'm Facing some strange issue while implementing RecyclerView

gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Activity JAVA Code:

```
RecyclerView rv_agenda = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_agenda);
AgendaAdapter agendaAdapter = new AgendaAdapter(mContext, BaseActivity.mDay1List);
rv_agenda.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
rv_agenda.getLayoutManager().setMeasurementCacheEnabled(false);
rv_agenda.setAdapter(agendaAdapter);
```

XML code :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv_agenda"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/vertical_spacing"/>
```

row_itemagenda.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_list_agenda_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/app_bg">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/constraint_agenda"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_agenda"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profileman" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/agenda_progress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_agenda_time"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="Agenda Titles"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium"
                android:textAllCaps="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_agenda_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/vertical_spacing"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/demo_str"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/text_caption"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_read_more"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/vertical_space"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
                android:text="@string/read_more"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_small"
                android:textAllCaps="false"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter Code :

```
public class Day1AgendaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Day1AgendaAdapter.AgendaViewHolder>
{
    AgendaActivity mContext;

    ArrayList<Day> mList = new ArrayList<>();

public Day1AgendaAdapter(AgendaActivity mContext, ArrayList<Day> mDayList)
{
    this.mContext = mContext;
    mList = mDayList;
}

@Override
public AgendaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_list_agenda, null);

    return new Day1AgendaAdapter.AgendaViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AgendaViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Day data = mList.get(position);

    holder.text_agenda_title.setText(data.getTitle());
    holder.text_agenda_time.setText(data.getFromTime()+" - "+data.getToTime());

    holder.text_agenda_title.setTypeface(mContext.getLightFonts());
    holder.text_agenda_time.setTypeface(mContext.getSemiBoldFonts());
    holder.btn_read_more.setTypeface(mContext.getRegularFonts());

    if(!data.getBackgroundColor().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        holder.layout_list_agenda_main.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(data.getBackgroundColor()));
    }
    else
    {
        holder.layout_list_agenda_main.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    }

    if(!data.getDescription().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        holder.btn_read_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.btn_read_more.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(data.getImage())
            .error(R.drawable.ic_image_holder)
            .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    holder.agenda_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    holder.agenda_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(holder.img_agenda);

    holder.btn_read_more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BaseActivity.AgendaId = BaseActivity.mDay1List.get(position).getAgendaId();
            Intent it = new Intent(mContext, AgendaDetailsActivity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(it);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

public class AgendaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView text_agenda_title,text_agenda_time;

    ImageView img_agenda;

    ProgressBar agenda_progress;

    LinearLayout layout_list_agenda_main;

    Button btn_read_more;

    public AgendaViewHolder(View convertView) {
        super(convertView);

        img_agenda = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_agenda);

        agenda_progress = convertView.findViewById(R.id.agenda_progress);

        text_agenda_title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_agenda_title);
        text_agenda_time = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_agenda_time);

        layout_list_agenda_main  = convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_list_agenda_main);

        btn_read_more = convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_read_more);
    }
}
}
```

**Do you know what i'm doing wrong here?**

My Agenda Item's all child item are dynamic with it's value title is multi line as well description and some items has button visible and gone so how can i achieve desire result by making item wrap_content.

have look on [image]

Comment: what is your desired result ? any clues ?. I can't tell from your code what kind of layout you want.

Comment: What happened? What result?

Comment: i have update question have look at the image

Comment: I think it's because you've set `weight=1` in the linear layout

Answer (score 0):

Your second `LinearLayout` has an orientation of horizontal and should be vertical if you want the `ConstraintLayout` and the next `LinearLayout` to be arranged vertically. There may be other things wrong, but I would start with this.